# with js set checked radio box issue with chose another by user

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have problem with checked radio box set up. I want make edit function, and  i have problem with my js code, who set checked value in my modal form (html code).

My variable `data[6]` holding value of name. And for example if my data[6] is  `Test`, then checking my radio box, where `id` is `EditTest` and then give that radio box label class checked.
Problem is then i want chose another one button, not the `Test` (different).
If i pick different radio box label, checked not change.

My js code.
first off all then clicked button in datatable edit, im clear all active and checked values.

```
$('input:radio').prop('checked', false);
$('label:has(input:not(:checked))').removeClass('active');
```

then  i by `id` give that radio box checked

```
$('#Edit' + data[6]).prop('checked', true);
$('label:has(input:checked)').addClass('active');
```

My html

```
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="EditEventType" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">TYPE:</label>
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-light btn-sm active">
                        <input type="radio" name="Editnone" id="Editnone"> None
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                      <input type="radio" name="EditTEST" id="EditTEST"> TEST
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                      <input type="radio" name="EditTESTTWO" id="EditTESTTWO"> TESTTWO
                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                      <input type="radio" name="EditTESTTHREE" id="EditTESTTHREE"> TESTTHREE
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('#Edit' + data[6]).closest("label")` to add active class to label where radio is checked and using
`$('.form-group label').removeClass('active');` remove active class from all label.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//on chnge or radio
$(".btn-group-toggle input:radio").on("change", function() {
  $('.btn-group-toggle label').removeClass('active'); //remove active class from lbel
  $('.btn-group-toggle input:radio').prop('checked', false);
  $(this).prop('checked', true); //add checkd true 
  $(this).closest("label").addClass('active');
})

$(".edit").on("click", function() {
  var data = "TEST" //data[6]
  $('input:radio').prop('checked', false);
  $('.form-group label').removeClass('active'); //remove active class from any label 
  $('#Edit' + data).prop('checked', true); //use data[6]
  //add active class to only label where radio is checked
  $('#Edit' + data).closest("label").addClass('active'); //use data[6]

})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label for="EditEventType" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">TYPE:</label>
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-light btn-sm active">
                        <input type="radio" name="Editnone" id="Editnone"> None
                    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                      <input type="radio" name="EditTEST" id="EditTEST"> TEST
                    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                      <input type="radio" name="EditTESTTWO" id="EditTESTTWO"> TESTTWO
                    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                      <input type="radio" name="EditTESTTHREE" id="EditTESTTHREE"> TESTTHREE
                    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="edit">edit</button>
```

Comment: your solution, allow select more than one radio box. I use radio box not checkbox because of what.

Comment: are there more such radios  or only these ?Also , `$('input:radio').prop('checked', false);` should remove checked from other radios .

Comment: Also change will happen on click of `edit` you need to remove checked from radio when it is clicked ? Check updated answer.